# Replace in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have the below two tables imported to power bi from SQL database:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>One</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Two</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Three</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>Four</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>Five</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1">
<tr><th>Selected Ids</th></tr>
<tr><td>1,2,3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1,3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>BLANK</td></tr>
<tr><td>BLANK</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now, i need to add a calculated column to the second table where Ids are replace with the Name. Like,

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><th>Selected Ids</th><th>Names</th></tr>
<tr><td>1,2,3</td><td>One,Two,Three</td></tr>
<tr><td>1,3</td><td>One,Three</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>One</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Three</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>One</td></tr>
<tr><td>BLANK</td><td>BLANK</td></tr>
<tr><td>BLANK</td><td>BLANK</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can i achieve this in an efficient manner and avoid creating multiple columns.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, There might be a better way, but I used Power Query to get this:

[image]

I started with this as Table1:

[image]

and this as Table2:

[image]

Then I worked within Table2's query.

Here's the M code:

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\mpincince\Desktop\SelectedIds.xlsx"), null, true),
Table2_Table = Source{[Item="Table2",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table2_Table,{{"SelectedIds", type text}}),

//The lines above established Table2. The following lines address your question...

#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Table1Copy" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Table1Copy", each Table1),
#"Expanded Table1Copy" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Table1Copy", "Table1Copy", {"Id", "Name"}, {"Id", "Name"}),
#"Added IdComparison" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table1Copy", "NameOfMatchedId", each if [SelectedIds]<> "" then (if Text.Contains([SelectedIds],[Id]) then [Name] else false) else null),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added IdComparison", each ([NameOfMatchedId] <> false)),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Index", "SelectedIds"}, {{"Names", each ([NameOfMatchedId])}}),
#"Extracted Values2" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {"Names", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values2",{"Index"})
in
#"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but if you want to accomplish this in DAX and not the query editor, you can use this formula; just replace "Table2" and "Names" with the names of your tables.

```
Names = IF(Table2[Selected Ids] = "BLANK", "BLANK",
IF(
    SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], 1, -1) = -1,
    LOOKUPVALUE(Names[Name], Names[Id], Table2[Selected Ids]),

    CONCATENATE(
        CONCATENATE(LOOKUPVALUE(Names[Name], Names[Id],
            MID(Table2[Selected Ids], 1, SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], 1, LEN(Table2[Selected Ids])) - 1)
            ), ","),

        IF(
            SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids],
                SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], 1, LEN(Table2[Selected Ids])) + 1,
                -1) = -1,

            LOOKUPVALUE(Names[Name], Names[Id],
                MID(Table2[Selected Ids], 
                    SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], 1, LEN(Table2[Selected Ids])) + 1, 
                    LEN(Table2[Selected Ids]) - SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], 1, LEN(Table2[Selected Ids]))
                    )
                ),

            CONCATENATE(
                CONCATENATE(LOOKUPVALUE(Names[Name], Names[Id],
                    MID(Table2[Selected Ids], 
                        SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], 1, LEN(Table2[Selected Ids])) + 1, 
                        SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], 1, LEN(Table2[Selected Ids])) + 1, LEN(Table2[Selected Ids])) - SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], 1, 0) - 1
                        )
                    ), ","),

                LOOKUPVALUE(Names[Name], Names[Id],
                    MID(Table2[Selected Ids], 
                    SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], 1, LEN(Table2[Selected Ids])) + 1, LEN(Table2[Selected Ids])) + 1, 
                    LEN(Table2[Selected Ids]) - SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], SEARCH(",", Table2[Selected Ids], 1, LEN(Table2[Selected Ids])) + 1, LEN(Table2[Selected Ids]))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image: Results]

This formula will only handle up to two commas. If you want to extend it to handle more, replace the last `LOOKUPVALUE` with another `IF` expanding each of the `SEARCH` functions to check for a third comma.